# Efficiently adding a new column to a Pandas DataFrame with values processed from an existing column?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a string column `foo` in my `DataFrame`. I need to create a new column `bar`, whose values are derived from corresponding `foo` values by a sequence of string-processing operations - a bunch of `str.split()`s and `str.join()`s in this particular case.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the vectorized string methods of pandas dataframes.
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/text.html#text-string-methods

```
# You can call whatever vectorized string methods on the RHS
df['bar'] = df['foo']
```

eg.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['a c', 'b d'], columns=['foo'])
df['bar'] = df['foo'].str.split(' ').str.join('-')
print(df)
```

yields

```
   foo  bar
0  a c  a-c
1  b d  b-d
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas can do this for you. A simple example might look like:

```
foo = ["this", "is an", "example!"]

df = pd.DataFrame({'foo':foo})
df['upper_bar'] = df.foo.str.upper()
df['lower_bar'] = df.foo.str.lower()
df['split_bar'] = df.foo.str.split('_')
print(df)
```

which will give you

```
       foo   upper_bar  lower_bar   split_bar
0      this      THIS      this      [this]
1     is an     IS AN     is an     [is an]
2  example!  EXAMPLE!  example!  [example!]
```

See the link above from Alex